# Table Elements Re-Positioning on Hover

Tags: html, css

UPDATE: Here's a link to the live version of this site: http://www.moblah.com/moblah.html

For whatever reason the issue happens more consistently there than in the fiddle I linked to below.

Okay, so as you'll see in the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/t7dWk/), I've got some `div`s as `td` elements, whose border changes from gray to orange on hover. However, in Chrome (at least I haven't been able to reproduce this issue in FF), about 1/3 of the time, upon hover, the `div`s move up a couple px. The issue goes away if I get rid of this:

```
div.table:hover {
    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

But something tells me that the hover is not the cause. Seems like a margin/padding issue, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Tried `border-collapse`, `vertical-align` and adding a couple px margins or padding to the elements. Any ideas?

Oh, and let me reiterate: this issue happens AROUND 1/3 OF THE TIME, so if you're not seeing the problem, you may have to repeat the action a few times. Maybe a bunch of times. It seems to occur more regularly if the cursor is not within the borders of the hidden `div` when it slides down. Thanks in advance for any suggestions . . .

Comment: Not seeing any movement in Chrome here.

Comment: @j08691: This is maddening. I just re-checked the fiddle and was unable to reproduce it myself. I'm going to update the OP with a link to the live site. It happens much more regularly there, if you're using Chrome.